# Python Library Interference

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have python 3 on my pc.  I had downloaded a SW written in python by a colleague.  His SW would not run on my pc unless I uninstalled matplotlib because it referenced the same library.  Now, I have another SW I just downloaded that also uses that library once again making the oringal SW useless. I downloaded matplotlib again and th new SW has no conflict. What can I change in the original SW so it will run?

Comment: Really hard to tell with no code or error messages.  Did they have a file called `matplotlib.py`?  That will definitely cause a namespace clash...

Comment: Just make an empty conda or pipenv environment an run the code there

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  There is no error code.  The SW starts with a .bat file.  An empty dos window opens and then immediately closes.  I had to remove my matplotlib to have it run initially so there may be multiple conflicts..  I have download Anaconda.  I will try the empty environment.